# Difference between Create login, credential and user in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I am bit confused about sqlserver Login, Credentials and User.
How they are connected or mapped?

When we are using connection string in asp.net what are we using Login or credentials..

Thank you.

Comment: chance duplicate ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750534/what-is-the-difference-between-login-and-credential-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Yes, I saw that question but I didn't get my answer.

Comment: then ok, check my ans

Answer (score 2):

***Login:*** 
A login is any principal that is granted access to a SQL Server instance.  The access can be granted to domain users, domain group, or SQL Server authenticated accounts.

***Credential:***
 A credential provides a mechanism to store login information for a domain account within SQL Server.  The credential can then be used to pass that authentication information from into another login or a proxy to grant it permissions to resources external to SQL Server.

**.....use of Login**
if you need to login and access a SQL Server instance, you’ll just use a login.  Regardless of your needs, if you need to get in and do work, the login is through route to go.  The other two won’t help you out at all.

**Use of credentials**..
Credentials get brought in when permissions from domain users need to be granted to accounts or services that wouldn’t usually have those permissions.  For instance, if an assembly required EXTERNAL_ACCESS, those permissions could be granted through the use of a credential.  Credentials can also be used to grant SQL Authentication accounts access to external resources.

Comment: When we are using Connecting string in asp.net web.config what we are using Login or Creddentails?

Comment: if u are using any Username and Password in your connection string  then you are using Sql credentials it is not windows authentication. So if u have already a sql username and password then no need to create a login again if not then - go into your Security section of your SQL Server and create a new Login with the connection sting Username and Password

Comment: if already have a Sql Login then u can use it , or if u want to create another then u can create a new login too. Anyway if u are write your connection string in webconfig then u must encrypt that ,other wise hackers can easily access your data

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
There two cases here. Please see below what we use.
1. Connection string doesn't contain UID and Password ->
Login or Credentails

2. Connection string contain UID and Password ->
Login or Credentails

And which case we use Login and Credentilas for Connection string.

Comment: i think you are not clear with the concept of login and credentials . First understand the concept i will explain it in simple manner- "A login is simply credentials for accessing SQL Server" example, you provide your username and password when logging on to Windows or even your e-mail account. This username and password build up the credentials. Therefore, credentials are simply a username and a password.authentication information (credentials) required to connect to a resource outside SQL Server.

Comment: This information is used internally by SQL Server. Most credentials contain a Windows user name and password.
i think now u got the concept of login and credentials ...in your scenario  your connection string does'nt contain any uid and password then you must go for windows authentication and set: Integrated Security=True";or Trusted_Connection=Yes;in your connection string .The second case u have password and if u have already created a login with these username and password then just use that other wise you want to create that in sql

Comment: above  two comments are continuation . so read both. if u have doubt again then tell me what you are trying to achieve through your program ,and what problems u are faced

Comment: In both login and credential case we are giving uid and password. So which one should be use in connection string for sqlserver authentication.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18829/discussion-between-arun-prasanth-and-manaskumar).

Answer (score 1):

Simply put

**Login** is used to grant instance level permissions. Let's say to connect to a sql server instance.

**Credential** is just used to grant access to a user outside the sql instance.

Let's say a "user1" is having access to sql server. Another user "AzureStorageuser" has access to AzureBlob storage. When "user1" needs to access AzureBlob storage, they need to have credentials. Merely having a login will not do.